# Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Tags: ios, swift

Хочу сохранить данные полученные с парсы при помощи UserDefaults, но показывает данную ошибку Attempt to set a non-property-list object

[image: Код]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно "данные полученные с парсы" но, если я правильно понял, и вы используете `Codable` то сохранять нужно так:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let encodedGroup = try encoder.encode(group)
    saveData.set(encodedGroup, forKey: "grouppp")
} catch {
    print("Save Failed")
}
```

или

```
let groupData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: group)
saveData.set(groupData, forKey: "grouppp")
```

и поменяйте

```
var grouppp = UserDefaults.standard
var saveData = UserDefaults.standard
```

на

```
let saveData = UserDefaults.standard
```

и проверка ниже ничего не проверяет

```
if true {
    print("saved")
}
```

---

Если ваш обект `group` типа `PFObject` то просто реализуйте в нем протокол `Codable` и сохраняйте как в примере вышею. [PFObject](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html) не реализует протокол `NSCoding`. В такомм случае для objC нужно было бы реализовать протокол `NSCoding`, а для Swift - протокол `Codable`

И неплохой [мануал](https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/migrating-to-codable-from-nscoding-ddc2585f28a4) по `Codable`

Comment: А как теперь реализовать получение данных? У меня приложение с расписанием для студентов, я хочу при первой входе сохранять данные(вы выше описали это) а теперь мне нужно эти данные брать при втором входе, как это можно оформить?

Comment: Ну смотрите вы из дефолтов по ключу получите Data и если для сохранения вы использовали encode , то теперь нужно использовать decode. Все тоже самое только в обратном порядке